# how to use arabic content in jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have tried to export jasper report with in the aracbic content through java program. I have set the locale [arabic] in jasper page and also set the locale in my java program. But i can't get the arabic data in my report. It Shows the arabic datas are ?????????????. So anybody guide me for the further steps?.

Thanks in Advance
Regards
zita

Comment: Bozho answer should be enough, if the problem still exists please add more information or choose a Best answer.

Comment: you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359978/how-to-show-arabic-hebrew-etc-language-fonts-on-jasper-ireport-reports/23359979#23359979

Answer (score 0):

```
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
```