# How to show arabic,Hebrew,etc language fonts on jasper (iReport) reports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have this simple tabular report with many columns with different types .

But when printing the report with **rtf (word)** extension

the columns with numbers or date    `appears on the report`.
the columns with with Arabic content `appear on the report`.

But when printing the report with **PDF** extension

the columns with numbers or date    `appears on the report`.
the columns with with Arabic content **DOES NOT** `appear on the report`.

I have tried many different fonts and changed properties like PDF embed and PDF encoding.
What is the right way to do this ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I faced this problem and its very annoying so to make it clear to all here how you do this

on the field or label that may has Arabic content go to its properties by right click or on the properties pallet of it , and make these changes

1. Check the box `PDF embed`
2. Choose `Identity-H` (Unicode with horizontal writing) from `PDF encoding`
3. Choose the font `Arial` if not there add it to the jasper fonts folder in the installation directory
   and add it to the `class path in settings`

Rerun in PDF mode ... it will work

Comment: Where is the font folder of the installation directory? I'm not able to find it?

Comment: As in step 3 it should be in installation folder, keep in mind this answer is since 2015, you may improve/update it ))

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar issue with Arabic text and found above solution helps but it leads to another issues like JVM doesn't have Arial etc. And also we need to configure these properties on each and every field. Following configuration worked for me with the jasper latest versions.

1. Use DejaVu Sans font(I used DejaVu Sans Mono)
2. Add jasperreports-fonts dependency(In my case Jasper report version is 6.4.0 & jasper-fonts version is 6.0.0)
3. If you need right to left layout use mirroring trick mentioned in
   [iReport - How to change report direction to RTL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324264/ireport-how-to-change-report-direction-to-rtl)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found this !!!
I'm using Jasper **6.17.0**

Step 1: Download Arial font from website.

Step 2: Place this ttf file in the server path. eg. `/app/jasper/Templates/TemplateFonts/`

Step 3: Select text field/static field from the Jasper Design screen, In the `Properties > Advanced > PDF provide below`

PDF Embedded : **true**

PDF Encoding : **Identity-H (Unicode with horizontal writing)**

PDF Font Name : `/app/jasper/Templates/TemplateFonts/arial.ttf`

Try now :)