# arabic is not showing in ireport pdf java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

hi I have a report that is build on Ireport version 5.6 The report is working fine but it is not showing Arabic that are in static text field. I have not used any font. Please guide step wise how to add font in ireport and which .ttf is needed for Arabic and from where i can get it. When i am exporting report in html format it shows Arabic but it is not showing colors. 
Also is there any way how to high light first row in detail band and is there any other reporting tool that is better than ireport in java

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359978/how-to-show-arabic-hebrew-etc-language-fonts-on-jasper-ireport-reports

Comment: I have used this but still getting problem can you provide me the URL of exact ttf of arial or from where i can get this . Second how to use same when generating report from java

Comment: Duplicate: [how to add arabic identity font in ireport 5.6 java not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41064302/876298)

Comment: Please, don't post the same question twice

Comment: i have done it 
1. Download arial .tff file 
2. click tools >>> options >> fonts >> install font >> select arial.tff
3. select all field contains arabic and change font

Answer (score -2):

I have Solved it

1. Download arial .tff file 
   In Ireport version 5.6
2. click tools then options then fonts then install font >> select arial.tff
3. select all fields that contain arabic and change font

Comment: "click tools >>> options " Where ? In which application do you "click tools" and in which applicatino do you "select all fields and change font" ?